# How to install a program on the load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, zerotier

I've created a web application using Beanstalk. I want to install a program on the load balancer. It's Zerotier (a program that enable you to create a local network over the internet). However, I'm not able to find a way to login to the load balancer server to do that. I know that I can install the program directly in the EC2 instance but the problem here is that the program will stop working when auto scaled.

Comment: AWS load balancers is a fully managed service. You can't install anything on them.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I want to deploy a web application on AWS and make it only accessable in my Zerotier local network.

Comment: You should still be able to do that in a single SubNet/AZ. You can limit an AutoScaleGroup to a single SubNet/AZ. I'm just not sure what benefits Zeroteir offers? What's the end aim here?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I'm only using AWS for the web application. So Zerotier is the way I'm connecting my devices together.

Comment: @BuSaeed right, maybe consider using a VPN connection from your local network.. I checked the website "It Just Works" so **perhaps read their documentation**. I'd go with an inbuilt AWS service and would use Cloud Formation scripts to set it up. Beanstalk is a service for developers who don't understand AWS (EC2s, Subnets, AZs, ELBs, IGW, etc).

Comment: @JeremyThompson Using an additional server as a proxy will make the load balancer useless. Instead I would rather use a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

install and add the program by making a deployment or service, not in the load balancer but in the cluster, your load balancer will help you to divide the work equally. on AWS its automatically provide you with the Load Balancer.

```
A load balancer serves as the single point of contact for clients. The load balancer distributes incoming application traffic across multiple targets, such as EC2 instances, in multiple Availability Zones. This increases the availability of your application. You add one or more listeners to your load balancer.
```

[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html)

Comment: That requires an additional server.